# Doppelkonjunktionen zwischen zwei Hauptsätze, allgemein

Tags: word-order, conjunction, main-clause

Ich lerne *die Doppelkonjunktionen zwischen zwei Hauptsätzen*, aber mein Buch ist oberflächlich und ich verstehe es nicht gut.

Die Doppelkonjunktionen, die ich lerne, sind:

> *sowohl … als auch …*
>
> *nicht nur … sondern auch …*
>
> *weder … noch …*
>
> *entweder … oder …*

Ich habe aus meinem Buch die folgende Beispiele:

> Frische sind *sowohl* bescheiden *als* auch kreativ
>
> Stiere sind *nicht nur* charmante, *sondern auch* friedfertige Menschen
>
> Geld macht *weder* reich *noch* glücklich
>
> Jan möchte *entweder* nach Italien *oder* nach Spanien fahren.

Ich möchte wissen, ob die Sätze mit den Doppelkonjunktionen die folgende *allgemein* (ohne Apokopen oder Ellipsen, und so weiter) sind:

> *Sowohl* sind Frische bescheiden *als auch* Fische sind kreativ
>
> *Nicht nur* sind Stiere charmante, *sondern auch* Stiere sind friedfertige Menschen
>
> *Weder* macht Geld reich *noch* Geld macht glücklich
>
> *Entweder* möchte Jan nach Italien fahren *oder* Jan möchte nach Spanien fahren.

Ich hoffe die Sache richtig erklärt zu haben.

Comment: Die Wiederholung des Subjektes klingt allerdings merkwürdig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich stelle anhand deiner Beispiele fest, wie hinterhältig und gemein die Wortreihenfolge in Sätzen im Deutschen ist. Nur zwei müssten wie folgt korrigiert werden (Zum vierten siehe weiter unten):

> Nicht nur sind Stiere charmante, sondern auch *sind Stiere* friedfertige Menschen
>
> Weder macht Geld reich noch *macht Geld* glücklich

---

Nicht alle Konstruktionen erlauben es. Und selbst bei denen, die es erlauben, ist die Verwendung unüblich. Sobald man irgendeine Dopplung (Subjekt, Verb) vermeiden kann, wird man das tun. Am ehesten würde man es in logischen Rätseln finden. Beispiele:

> Entweder fährt Jan nach Italien, oder Silke fliegt nach Spanien.
>
> Weder kosten Äpfel 1 €, noch zahlt man für Birnen 1,50 €.

*Sowohl … als auch* impliziert für meinen Geschmack zu sehr eine Zusammengehörigkeit, weswegen ich es nur in zusammengehörenden Fällen benützen würde, und in diesen Fällen auch das Wiederholte wegließe. Dieses Beispiel hier ist für mich das Äußerste an Auseinanderziehung, das ich noch gutheißen kann:

> Europa wurde sowohl von einem Gespenst heimgesucht als auch von einem Eisernen Vorhang getrennt.

*Nicht nur … sondern auch* ist so ein Zwischen-Fall … Es ist immer noch unschön, es für ganze Sätze zu benutzen, aber es geht leidlich. Idealerweise würdest du *sondern auch* trennen, und das *auch* im Satz einreihen:

> Nicht nur sind Stiere charmante Menschen, *sondern* Fische sind *auch* kreative Menschen

Beachte, dass ich den Satz immer noch für grenzwertig halte (wobei er mir als Stier doch auch sehr schmeichelt).

Answer (score 3):

Leider darf ich noch keine Kommentare schreiben (da würde es vielleicht besser hingehören). Die Sätze hören sich noch nicht ganz richtig an, hier meine Vorschläge (aber ich verstehe deine Frage auch noch nicht ganz):

> > Sowohl sind Frische bescheiden als auch Fische sind kreativ.
>
> Fische sind sowohl bescheiden als auch kreativ.
>
> > Nicht nur sind Stiere charmante, sondern auch Stiere sind friedfertige Menschen.
>
> Stiere sind nicht nur charmant, sondern auch friedfertig.
>
> oder
>
> Nicht nur sind Stiere charmant, sie sind auch friedfertig.
>
> > Weder macht Geld reich noch Geld macht glücklich.
>
> Geld macht weder reich noch glücklich.
>
> oder
>
> Weder macht Geld reich noch macht es glücklich.
>
> > Entweder möchte Jan nach Italien fahren oder Jan möchte nach Spanien fahren.
>
> Jan möchte entweder nach Italien oder Spanien fahren.